# How to remove odd border from value part of input element in Safari?

Tags: html, css, input, safari

If you have a look at this pic - http://twitpic.com/q0a6p - you can see a strange issue with an outline around the text element of a input tag in a form. (on the right, it is being inspected by Safari's web inspector). The background is the image of the button. The problem only occurs in Safari. FF and IE is fine. Does anyone have any idea what is causing it?

```
<input type='image'  id='product_114' class='buy_button' name='Buy' value='Add To Cart'  />
```

I've applied border:none !important to the input element but the outline still shows (only in Safari). It appears to be outlining the value part of the input element, but I'm not sure how to style that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input type="image">` element has more caveats. In for example IE, you wouldn't receive `buy` as parameter name, but `buy.x` and `buy.y`.

The `<input type="image">` is merely meant to present some kind of a **map** wherein the end-user would be able to point specific locations in.

But you don't want to do that. You just want a submit button with a **background** image. I would thus suggest to replace it by an `<input type="submit">` with a CSS `background-image` which is set to `url(path/to/your/image.png)`.

As to the outline: this is more a matter of the background position.

Comment: thanks. changing it to submit worked. i'm still mystified as to why the border appeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's an input of "image" type, you don't need to put a value attribute to it, instead use the alt attribute.
Plus I don't see the src attribute.

Your input should look more like :

```
<input type='image'  src='path/to/your/image.png' id='product_114' class='buy_button' name='Buy' alt='Add To Cart'  />
```

You can also custom a link using jquery like this :

HTML:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <a href="#" id="submit-link"/>
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(#submit-link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#my-form").submit();
});
```

Comment: There is no src because I am using background-image in the CSS to provide the image. Changing value to alt has no effect

Comment: I added another solution in my answer, feel free to try it out.